# How can I require a minimal kernel version for a deb package?

Tags: dpkg, deb

I am trying to make a deb package of software for makinging a NAS out of an Ubuntu installation. The software requires kernel patches to be applied therefore the package must use a special kernel build where I have applied the patches. How can I require a minimum kernel version requirment. Right now I am basing my stuff off of kernel 2.6.38-12.51-scst. But in the future I will update the kernel to stay current as much as possible. How can I setup the deb package to allow for the current kernel and ones to follow? They will all be tagged with `-scst` from this point on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the control file for the .deb package, you can set the dependency line to require it.

```
Depends: kernel (>= 2.6.38-12.51)
```

I do not know the exact package name, but that's an example of the line.

Comment: @Solignis if this helped you and worked, perhaps you should mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Yep just, did sry about the delay.

Comment: @SimonSheehan Do you need that entire version string or can I just do `kernel (>= 2.6.38)` as a valid check?

Comment: @ChefPharaoh I don't currently have a machine to test that. Let me know if it does work though!

Comment: @SimonSheehan Yes, seems to be working with just the main build number, which is a good thing for my purpose ;)